# Set http-only on cookies created in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I need to restrict access to a cookie containing a session token so that javascript can't access it.
Advice that was given was to set Secure and HttpOnly flags on the cookie.

I was having trouble with cookies not being set when using @ResponseBody, so I'm setting the cookies inside a HandlerInterceptor.

```
public class COOKIEFilter implements org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor  {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("timestamp", new Long(new Date().getTime()).toString());
        cookie.setSecure(true);
        // how do I set the http-only flag?
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);

        return true;
    }
```

As shown in the chrome console, Secure is set, but not HTTP

[image: Showing that secure flag is being set]

I've tried adding parameters to web.xml under servlet 3.0 sepcification that allows for secure and http-only to be set on session cookies, but since I need to handle the session myself (Spring MVC application needs to remain stateless), that won't work for me.

Update:

I'm using Tomcat7, currently with Servlet 2.5 and Spring 3.2.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be set as `cookie.setHttpOnly(true)` just like you did for secure.

Comment: Let me try upping the servlet specification to 3

Comment: i haven't used Sping MVC framework, but this works in Java servlet. Is the `Cookie` you use from `javax.servlet.http.Cookie`?

Comment: That is correct: javax.servlet.http.Cookie; From which servlet version is setHttpOnly supported?

Comment: Java EE 6 [Cookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html)

Comment: It says `Since: Servlet 3.0`, let me go figure out how to make make Spring play nice with Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `HttpOnly` as below:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("timestamp", new Long(new Date().getTime()).toString() + ";HttpOnly");
```

It needs to follow `cookieName=cookieValue;HttpOnly;Secure` format

Comment: The value I'm seeing in Chrome Console is now `"1427955789419`, but no HTTP flag is set.

Comment: You mean to say that after the above changes, you are still not seeing the `HttpOnly` ?

Answer (score -2):

Replace:

```
 Cookie cookie = new Cookie("timestamp", new Long(new Date().getTime()).toString());
```

with the following

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("timestamp", new Long(new Date().getTime()).toString()+";HttpOnly");
```

This might work.

Comment: That just sets the value to "1427955447675 Http-Only"

Comment: Yeah I missed to put the ; .As you said that too doesn't works. May I know which server you're using. Because, some server level configuration might cause conflicts