# How to set secure flag true in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I am not getting how to set flag secure to true in `spring mvc`.
I have tried the following four ways but I'm unable to get any solution:

1) [Set http-only on cookies created in Spring MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406002/set-http-only-on-cookies-created-in-spring-mvc-controller)

2) [Forcing Tomcat to use secure JSESSIONID cookie over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989396/forcing-tomcat-to-use-secure-jsessionid-cookie-over-http)

3) https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag

4) https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/session-cookie-httponly-flag-java/

I have tried this code also and placed in `web.xml`
`<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
       <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
       </cookie-config>
</session-config>`

but it's not working.

i have tried using `java`:

`Cookie cookie = new Cookie("timestamp", new Long(new Date().getTime()).toString());
cookie.setSecure(true);`

I placed above code in `Interceptor`
 but this is also not working.

When I check in my browser/resources to check whether my flag is set to secure or not.
but none of the ways is working.
Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: what is *"When I see in my browser/resources ito check whether my flag is set to secure or not"* supposed to mean? Could you please translate your entire question into english?

Comment:   unexptected from stackoverflow people